# OpenAPI for pagination and sorting

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, openapi

I have pretty common case where GET Endpoint should accept pagination and sorting parameters. REST Contract is writing with OpenAPI. And the aim is to be able to receive something like such an object:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Paging:
      type: object
      properties:
        page:
         type: integer
        limit:
         type: integer
        sorting:
         $ref: '#/components/schemas/Sorting'
    Sorting:
      type: object
      properties:
        attr:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/comonents/schemas/SortingAttr'
    SortingAttr:
      type: object
      properties:
       sortyBy:
         $ref: '#/components/schemas/SortyByEnum'
       direction:
         $ref: '#/components/schemas/SortDirectionEnum'
   SortByEnum:
     type: string
     enum: [ PROP1, PROP2 ]
   SortDirectionEnum:
     type: string
     enum: [ ASC, DESC ]
```

As a workaround I use POST Request and provide object 'Paging' as a body and thus get this nested object in controller. However, this does not work as query parameter for GET request.

Is there another way to get following query params?

- page
- limit
- array of sorting params: [{sortParam, sortDirection}]

Comment: `And the aim is to be able to receive something like such an object` Regular query string parameters do the job just fine. There is no added value in wrapping them into object structures. Use as few params as reasonably possible, keep it simple for clients. `I use POST Request` --> defeats client-side caching and is not RESTful so yes, you need to use GET.